# Angular2: CoreModule vs SharedModule

Tags: angular

Could somebody explain what's a `SharedModule` and a `CoreModule` stand for?

I've been watching several project out there are using this approach in order to build its angular projects.

1. Why do I need two modules?
2. When should I import each one?
3. Which `imports`, `exports`, `declarations` should each one have?

Comment: I know it's been already 7 months since you asked this, but since the other answers were not complete and/or misleading and you didn't accept any of them, I have tried to answer it in details. Please accept it if you think it's being correctly answered to help other people that might have the same doubt. Cheers!

Comment: I wrote an article to make this two concepts clear, you can find it here: https://medium.com/@benmohamehdi/angular-best-practices-coremodule-vs-sharedmodule-25f6721aa2ef

Answer (score 200, accepted):

## TLDR:

1. `CoreModule` should have only `services` and be imported only once in the `AppModule`.
2. `SharedModule` should have anything but `services` and be imported in all modules that need the shared stuff (which could also be the `AppModule`).

But:

> Real-world modules are often hybrids that purposefully deviate from the [above] guidelines. These guidelines are not laws; follow them unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

---

## [RTFM](https://xkcd.com/293/):

So, after going through the whole [NgModules' docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules) (plus some other stuff to understand the context), I easily found **the answer for your 2nd and 3rd questions**
[there](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-kinds-of-modules-should-i-have-and-how-should-i-use-them). Here are they:

### SharedModule

> - Create a `SharedModule` with the `components`, `directives`, and `pipes` that you use everywhere in your app. This module should consist entirely of `declarations`, most of them exported.

- The `SharedModule` may re-export other widget modules, such as `CommonModule`, `FormsModule`, and modules with the UI controls that you use most widely.
- The `SharedModule` should not have `providers` for reasons explained previously. Nor should any of its imported or re-exported modules have providers. If you deviate from this guideline, know what you're doing and why.
- Import the `SharedModule` in your feature modules, both those loaded when the app starts and those you lazy load later.

### CoreModule

> - Create a `CoreModule` with `providers` for the singleton services you load when the application starts.

- Import `CoreModule` in the root `AppModule` only. Never import `CoreModule` in any other module.
- Consider making `CoreModule` a pure services module with no `declarations`.

Although these are more detailed than the `TLDR` version above and you now can go on and keep coding, it mentions some things that you have to read the docs to understand (i.e. 'widget module", "reasons explained previously", "pure service modules"), and it also **doesn't answer your 1st question**.

So let's try to do that!

---

### Why do I need two modules?

You *don't need* two modules. This is what is in the docs:

> The root module is all you need in a simple application with a few components.

With that said, it's important to make a different question first:

#### Why do people organize their projects into multiple modules?

The basic explanation for this comes right after the above statement in the docs:

> As the app grows, you refactor the root module into feature modules that represent collections of related functionality. You then import these modules into the root module.

But you asked "why?" and this requires more than a basic explanation. So let's start explaining what are some *problems* that can happen if your app starts to grow and you *don't separate* functionalities into feature modules:

- The root module starts to become cluttered, with a code that is difficult to read and work with, since it must import all dependencies (e.g. 3rd party Modules), provide all services and declare all components, directives, and pipes. The more the app needs, the bigger this module will be.
- The different functionalities don't have a clear boundary between them, making it more difficult, not just to understand the app's structure, but also to have different responsibilities on a team.
- You can start having to solve conflicts between different parts of your app. For example, if you have directives or components that do the same thing in two different parts of your app, you'll either have to start using longer names to differentiate them or to rename them when importing.

Although you may think that the examples above are not exactly problems (maybe you work alone and can live with your own mess or all of your teammates are also messy), keep in mind that other people will certainly  not agree with you and that's why you *"have been watching several project[s] out there ... using this approach"*.

Considering that you agree with that and want to organize your growing app into feature modules, please note the following statements from the docs:

> The root module and the feature module share the same execution context. They share the same dependency injector, which means the services in one module are available to all.
>
> The modules have the following significant technical differences:

- You boot the root module to launch the app; you import a feature module to extend the app.
- A feature module can expose or hide its implementation from other modules.

**Information to never forget:** *"services in one module are available to all [modules]", while other things, like Components, Directives, and Pipes must be injected in each module that wants to use them.*

With this information we can now go closer to what you want to know by answering the following question:

**Are all feature modules equal?**

**NO!** At least it is suggested that they shouldn't be equal, as it is suggested that you shouldn't have just the root module, but you can do whatever you want. But you shouldn't.

The docs have a table showing the differences between the suggested feature module groups. Let's take a look on an excerpt of it:

```
FEATURE   SHOULD HAVE    SHOULD HAVE   SHOULD HAVE
MODULE    DECLARATIONS   PROVIDERS     EXPORTS         

Domain    Yes            Rare          Top component   
Routed    Yes            Rare          No              
Routing   No             Yes (Guards)  RouterModule    
Service   No             Yes           No              
Widget    Yes            Rare          Yes
```

ATTENTION! They make it pretty clear that this is a...

> ...preliminary guidance based on early experience using
> NgModules in a few applications.

So, again, you're not stuck to this guidelines and deviations can happen, but you should know what you're doing and why.

Now let's analyze this table:

- The `Service` and `Widget` groups are the only ones that have completely different values between them in each column.
- The `Domain` and `Routed` groups are basically the same as the `Widget` group, only with limited or none exports.
- The `Routing` group is basically a `Service` group, with an export exception and limited to a specific provider.

So, let's consider the `Domain`, `Routed` and `Routing` groups just variants of `Service` or `Widget` and focus on these last two.

**Services** should call your attention. Remember that you should never forget that "services in one module are available to all [modules]"? Well, if they call a feature module group `Services`, that's because it must be isolated from the other modules so it can be imported only once. As an example, you can have an `UserModule` that consists of services like `SignUpService`, `SignInService`, `SocialAuthService` and `UserProfileService`. Wherever you import that `UserModule`, all of its services will be available app-wide. And as per the above table, it should not have declarations nor exports, just the providers.

**Widgets** sounds more generic, but it should tell you something. Remember that you should also never forget that *"other things, like Components, Directives, and Pipes must be injected in each module that wants to use them."*? So this is the type of module you will use for those. For example, you can have an `UIModule` with `ButtonComponent`, `NavComponent`, `SlideshowComponent`, `HighlightLinkDirective`, `CtaPipe`. And every time you need to use one or all of its exported elements, you import just the `UIModule`.

So, basically, due to how Angular deals with Services, when you start splitting functionalities into feature modules, you have to isolate the services into their own module(s), while the other stuff can be organized between them as you wish.

**How do `CoreModule` and `SharedModule` fit into this?**

To keep it simple, the `CoreModule` is a `Service` module and the `SharedModule` is a `Widget` module. And that's why you should import the first only once in the `AppModule` and the latter in all modules that need it. From my examples above, the `UserModule` would be imported by the `CoreModule` and the `UIModule` by the `SharedModule`.

But, as stated before, these are guidelines and deviations can happen, even in their own examples they declare components in the `CoreModule`, but with an observation:

> This page sample departs from that advice by declaring and exporting [in the `CoreModule`] two components that are only used within the root AppComponent declared by AppModule. Someone following this guideline strictly would have declared these components in the AppModule instead.

---

Personally, I think that the biggest confusion is regarding the naming choices. In general, people will think that everything that is part of your app's core (i.e. User stuff, NavBar, load bar, toasters etc) will go into the `CoreModule` and everything that's shared across multiple features would go into the `SharedModule`.

That's not actually true and a bit misleading, since all services are shared between all modules "by nature" and no service should be included in the `SharedModule`, as well as a `NavbarComponent` is part of the core of your app and no component should be included in the `CoreModule`.

In any case, the recommendation is to follow the guidelines until you find a reason not to do so.

And here is the rest of the table above to help better understanding the guidelines:

```
FEATURE   CAN BE                 SOME
MODULE    IMPORTED BY            EXAMPLES

Domain    Feature, AppModule     ContactModule (before routing)
Routed    Nobody                 ContactModule, DashboardModule,
Routing   Feature (for routing)  AppRoutingModule, ContactRoutingModule
Service   AppModule              HttpModule, CoreModule
Widget    Feature                CommonModule, SharedModule
```

Cheers!

Comment: Cool that you took the time to write all this. Can you comment on the following? In https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#core-feature-module they write: `Do gather application-wide, single use components in the CoreModule. Import it once (in the AppModule) when the app starts and never import it anywhere else. (e.g. NavComponent and SpinnerComponent).`. Do you see disadvantages with putting components like NavBarComponent in CoreModule? I upvoted your answer; but still, please comment on navbar in CoreModule, please :).

Comment: I bet (and hope) the guy who downvoted this answer did not do it on purpose

Comment: @mattarau If you need a component like "main menu" in some of the pages, should it go in shared module? Please note that main menu is not needed always but in some of the pages including home page.

Comment: @KarolDepka Unfortunately, the docs and the guideline are written by different people. But as mentioned in both of them, they are just suggestions and each project and developer might feel more comfortable deviating a bit from them. I personally would put a NavBarComponent directly into the AppModule.

Comment: @EresDev I'm not sure what you mean by 'page', but if each page has it's own module and just some of them will use the component, you clearly have a shared component there. But if you have a single PagesModule, where all pages components are declared, and this "main menu" is not used by any other module, you can simply import it in the PagesModule.

Comment: how do lazy feature modules get bundled? What if my shred module has 10 UI components. Feature 1 module uses only one of them and feature 2 uses another one. Will bundles for these feature modules include all the components from the shared module or just these that are used by them?

Comment: All references to `CoreModule` have been removed from the Angular Docs; it's no longer a recommended practice. The Singleton Services section using `providedIn: 'root'` seems to be the alternative https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Answer (score 4):

I do use this approach myself and here's why/how :
*(it's one approach and maybe other people will have != ideas which is fine)*

I like to keep the `app.module` as clean as possible. If you want to use universal or build your project with AOT (when not using angular-cli) you may need to have a duplicated app.module with small changes in all those files.

So if you import many modules into your `app.module`, you'll have to maintain that list up to date in different files.

**Here comes the `core.module` :**
Put every module you only want to import once here. Mainly, modules with `forRoot` methods (the ones that exports their providers and that should be imported only once).

Import also your providers here.
(if you use ngrx for example, declare your store here).

**Then, the `shared.module` :**
Put every module you'll have to reuse across your app (*CommonModule, HttpModule, RouterModule, MaterialModule, FlexLayoutModule, etc*).

**Finally, `app.module` :**
Import in `app.module` your `core.module` **ONLY HERE**. CoreModule should be loaded only once. In all your submobules, you can load the `SharedModule`.

With that configuration, if you need to create another app.module for universal or others, you don't have to copy and maintain the whole module list in different files. Simply import the `core.module` and you're good to go.

Comment: that is not what StyleGuide for Angular says. Unless I understood it wrong

Comment: Then what did you understand ?

Comment: "Do import all modules required by the assets in the CoreModule (e.g. CommonModule and FormsModule).". The StyleGuide also says to import CommonModule into SharedModule. What is the difference then?

Comment: I've made a small starter for ngrx that has this kind of setup, take a look https://github.com/maxime1992/angular-ngrx-starter/tree/master/src/app

Comment: but for modules I want to use across my app, I only really want to import them once WHICH IS WHERE MY CONFUSION LIES. KISS!

Comment: In the styleguide, you can read "Do import all modules required by the assets in the CoreModule (e.g. CommonModule and FormsModule)." AND "Do import all modules required by the assets in the SharedModule; for example, CommonModule and FormsModule." ... so I am still confused. Where should go CommonModule for example ?

Comment: @Maxime Your explanation can be a bit misleading since you say to import ALSO the providers in the CoreModule, while it should have only providers (Your starter project follows the docs though). Plese, check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

As per style guide of Angular and my observations:

**CoreModule(core.module.ts)** *Core feature module*

> All services that should be singleton should be provided here. For example `HelperService`, `LoggerService`.

Application wide component should be declared in `CoreModule` like `header`, `footer`.

CoreModule provides one or more singleton services. Angular registers the providers with the app root injector, making a singleton instance of each service available to any component that needs them, whether that component is eagerly or lazily loaded.

Only the root AppModule should import the CoreModule.

**SharedModule(shared.module.ts)** *Shared feature module*

> declare components, directives, and pipes in a shared module when those items will be re-used and referenced by the components declared in other feature modules

It is suggested to avoid using `services` in shared modules. Services are usually singletons that are provided once for the entire application or in a particular feature module.

Modules required by all feature modules should be imported in SharedModule like `CommonModule` & `FormsModule`.

Declaration of sharable component/pipe/directive should be in SharedModule. If these component/pipe/directive needs to be used by other feature module, they must exported.

If using Material, it's best place to import and re-export Angular Material components.

References:
[CoreModule](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#core-feature-module), [SharedModule](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module)

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is too general and for general question, you'll have general answers ... For example, shared module is meant to keep what several components/modules use :

```
import { NgModule }            from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }        from '@angular/common'; 
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

//import { AwesomePipe }         from './awesome.pipe';
//import { HighlightDirective }  from './highlight.directive';

@NgModule({
  exports:      [ /*AwesomePipe, HighlightDirective,*/
                  CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

CoreModule is more like what you consider to be the core of your page (Nav, Spinner, Alert...). This is very suggestive and depend on your feeling I think. For example:

```
import { NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';

import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { SpinnerComponent } from './spinner/spinner.component';
import { SpinnerService } from './spinner/spinner.service';
import { AlertComponent }     from './alert/alert.component';
import { AlertService }       from './alert/alert.service';

import { SharedModule }       from '../shared/shared.module';

import { CoreRoutingModule } from './core-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    SharedModule, 
    CoreRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports: [//Other modules use these components, so we export them
    AlertComponent, 
    NavComponent, 
    SpinnerComponent,

    ],
  declarations: [ //we use them in CoreModule, so we declare them
    AlertComponent, 
    NavComponent, 
    SpinnerComponent,

    ],
  providers: [
    SpinnerService, 
    AlertService,

  ]
})
export class CoreModule {
    constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
      if (parentModule) {
        throw new Error(
          'CoreModule est déjà chargé. Importer le uniquement dans AppModule');
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly true. Check my answer, where I explain why.

Comment: You should not import the SharedModule inside the CoreModule

Comment: @andreasonny83 why?

Comment: @KarolDepka is best practice to import the CoreModule inside your application's root module (AppModule in AngularCLI). All the reusable modules, to be installed inside your features modules, should reside inside a SharedModule. In this way, your root application won't need to load all the shared modules for bootstrapping your app. Importing the shared modules inside the CoreModule neutralize the benefit of having a SharedModule as they will be already installed inside your core application module.

Comment: @andreasonny83 Thank you. Could you clarify: for the end-user, is there a benefit of speeding up bootstrapping itself? Wouldn't the user have to wait anyway, for anything to be displayed, till SharedModule gets loaded anyway?

Comment: Sure @KarolDepka. This has nothing to do with performance or lazy-loading. It is just the suggested pattern to keep your code organized following best practices.
Your CoreModule should contain your singleton services, single-instance components, and export any third-party modules needed in AppModule. The SharedModule should contain common components/pipes/directives and also export commonly used Angular modules (like CommonModule from @angular/common for *ngIf directive).

Comment: how do you get to make the NavComponent routerLink to work if there is no RouterModule imported in the CoreModule